# Trying to scrape a site, but having issues on setting xpath to input dates on calendar

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to set some inputs on xpath to scrape a site. However when I set the input to grab the date on a calendar, I am having no luck on setting the dates.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="beginDate-DocumentType" data-mask="00/00/0000" maxlength="10" name="beginDate" title="Begin Date" style="width90px" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker valid"> == $0
```

PythonScrape

```
drv.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name=\"beginDate"]')\
    .send_keys(Start_Date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

From_Date `# Original Test Dates From_Date = date(2021, 7, 1) To_Date = date(2021, 7, 7)`

[Image with HTML and site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc91Y.png)

Comment: Are you sure your XPath is unique? What error do you see?

Comment: Why do you have a `\"` in your xpath? Also why don't you use the `id` attribute?

Comment: Hey there @Prophet the error I see is:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @Trapli Hey! I tried to use the ID as well but had no luck on getting the input on the webdriver

Comment: @Trapli I even tried to .send_keys the date written instead of putting Start_Date

Comment: If so you should add a delay or scroll the element into the view in case it is initially out of the view when you are trying to access it

Comment: @Prophet I've already tried to setup a delay (sleep) for 1 s and 5s and had the same issue.

Comment: Is that element inside the visible screen? What screen size have you set for the driver?

Comment: @Prophet the element is inside the screen, right underneath "AllDocument Types."

Comment: @Prophet The document is visible when I open the page, right underneath All document type

drv.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="documentCategory-DocumentType"]/option[text()="ALL DOCUMENT TYPES"]')\
        .click()
    sleep(5)
    drv.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name=\"beginDate"]')\
        .send_keys(Start_Date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

Comment: maybe you should click on some element to open some dialog etc. to make this element visible?

Comment: @Prophet I already found out what was wrong, I had to .clear the text and the send_keys

Comment: Ah, OK. I see. That's why it's always recommended to share as match as possible all the relevant code including the web page you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you seeing `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` error you can try solving it in the following ways:

1. Add a simple delay, like `time.sleep(5)` before you trying to access that element.
2. In case the element is out of the visible screen view you should first scroll that element into the view.